# How to make directory file system listing?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

So, I am trying to make a left panel for listing parent-child directory system in to react project. I am looking for a reference or package if available to start with.

I have a rudimentary approach for this using margin-left for the children. But, hoping there would a far better way to do it.

Following is the mock for left panel:

[image]

Using react with react-bootstrap

Comment: What are you expecting? A full written tutorial step by step? We are here to help you with specific programming related problems. We would expect you to describe an issue you're facing, ideally with the code you're using, so that we may then help you change that code into something that helps you. StackOverflow is not a `do it all for me` service.

Comment: @GBWDev you misunderstood. I am looking for a reference to start with. Also, I added some context.

Comment: @GauravKumar you could use https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tree. That's a different component library, though.

Comment: You can use `ul` and `li` combination. You can go on nesting into them. Having a constant left spacing should work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at NPM? 
One of the libraries that comes to mind is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-simple-tree-menu

Answer (score 0):

I used the material's tree component(although I am using react-bootstrap but WTH)

Credit to following user answer:

[How to change the collapse/expand icon to right side of TreeView of material?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819211/how-to-change-the-collapse-expand-icon-to-right-side-of-treeview-of-material)

Following is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-pine-dyy7j

Cheers